# How to get navbar elements to right?

Tags: html, css, web

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Company</a>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>

          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">On the right</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

I want 'On the right' on the right hand side but even after using "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" i am unable to do it. Can anyone plz explain me how to do it? New learner here. Thanks for your help

Comment: Nevermind guys, i found my mistake a div was missing. Thank you everyone for the response.

Answer (score 0):

set `.navbar-header {width: 100%}` and you're good to go.

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fb1cd24m/1/)

```css
.navbar-header {width: 100%}
```

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Company</a>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>

          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">On the right</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I reccomend just using vanilla css (especially if you are a new learner).

To implement in vanilla css do something like this.

```html
<nav class="nav">
  <div>
    <a href="#">Company</a>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">On the right</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<style>
  nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
</style>
```

Learn vanila css before using any framework.

Answer (score 0):

How about this one?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="nav navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="">
          <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Company</a>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Item One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Item Two</a></li>

          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">On the right</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      
  </body>
</html>
```